# Why is gcc not ignoring comment as error when using #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcomment"?

Tags: c++, g++, pragma

I have some comments that have some macro examples.  To make them more readable, I end the line with a `\` to continue the macro on the next line.  I'd rather not put a space after the `\` to remove the problem if a dev copies the code without expecting trailing spaces as well as our git commit standards don't like trailing spaces.  Also, our coding standards prohibit the use of multiline comments (`/* */`) and our documentation uses triple slashes (`///`) not (`/** ... */)` style comments.  Our compiler has `-Wall -Werror` set, so I want to temporarily disable this error.  Example code follows:

```c++
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcomment"
// boo \
// hoo
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jT76575qv)</kbd>

Unfortunately, the compiler is still complaining about this error.  We're using 7.5, but this still doesn't work under the latest 12.2.

The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) say:

> `#pragma GCC diagnostic kind option`
>
> Modifies the disposition of a diagnostic. Note that not all diagnostics are modifiable; at the moment only warnings (normally controlled by ‘-W…’) can be controlled, and not all of them. Use `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to determine which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them.

What it doesn't say is *how* `-fdiagnostics-show-option` can determine which diagnostics are controllable, which is annoying.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a pre-processor warning and is not controlled by #pragma.

Comment: @273K Sounds like an answer to me. I was stuck and confused for 10 minutes.

Comment: @273K, why would it not be?  `#pragma` is a preprocessor command, so it is in the rigth context.  Do you have any reference to support this?

Comment: Why were you stuck and confused @PasserBy?

Comment: Some directives may be duplicated in the output of the preprocessor. These are ‘#ident’ (always), ‘#pragma’ (only if the preprocessor does not handle the pragma itself)

Comment: Although not officially documented, diagnostic pragmas can't take effect on the preprocessor's warnings. Intuitively, the comments warnings are already thrown **before** `ignored` works.

Comment: @Nimrod, might be intuitive if you know the internals, but from a UX perspective, not intuitive at all.

Comment: @Adrian the compiling process can be divided into several [steps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases). These macros only take effect after the preprocessor finishes its work. However, the preprocessor fails here. So the rest process stalls.

Comment: @JaMiT, has to do with my team's coding standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splicing together of lines when one ends in `\` happens in the second [phase of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases). The determination of what is a comment happens in the third phase. At this point, gcc has all the information it needs to emit that warning. Why wait?

The `#pragma` lines are processed in phase 4, too late to stop the warning in question. Maybe the warning could be delayed, but given that not all diagnostics are modifiable, I don't see priority given to delaying a warning merely to subject it to a `#pragma`.

---

> What it doesn't say is *how* `-fdiagnostics-show-option` can determine which diagnostics are controllable, which is annoying.

I think the documentation is misleading. I do not see how this option can be used to determine which diagnostics are controllable, other than trial and error. What I see it helping with is determining "which option controls them" (sort of—this option is on by default). This option controls the display of the command line options controlling the warnings that are emitted.

For example, with `-fdiagnostics-show-option` (the default):

```
warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
```

With `-fno-diagnostics-show-option` (negating the default):

```
warning: multi-line comment
```

So this is useful for determining the command line option for a particular warning, which can in turn be used to try to ignore the warning. If the `#pramga` works, then the warning is one that can be controlled via `#pragma` (not exactly a mind-blowing deduction).

Comment: Annoyingly unhelpful (gcc, not your answer). ☹

Comment: _"At this point, gcc has all the information it needs to emit that warning. Why wait?"_ Because it doesn't? :D Some ppl want to disable this warning. :P

Comment: @Adrian *"Because it doesn't?"* -- I think you mean it does not have all the information it would need to **suppress** that warning. I wrote "to emit that warning". Subtly different criterion. ;)

Comment: Or emit **no** warning. ;)

Comment: @Adrian "*Or emit no warning."* -- Actually, the compiler does have information about emitting no warning. The compiler will not emit the warning if it is turned off via the command line (`-Wno-comment`). It's still just overriding the command line that is missing. *(You could run your experiment in reverse. Specify `-Wno-comment` on the command line, and change "ignored" to "error" to get `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wcomment"` -- compilation will pass, even though this `#pragma` tries to turn the situation into an error. The compiler does not wait to see if maybe an override will come.)*

Comment: @Adrian *"Annoyingly unhelpful (gcc"* -- you could request a change from gcc. However, instead of requesting that this warning be controlled by `#pragma`, I would request that the definition of `-Wcomment` be changed. Instead of warning "whenever a backslash-newline appears in a ‘//’ comment", it should warn when a backslash-newline appears in a ‘//’ comment **that is not immediately followed by '//'**. The point of this aspect of the warning is to warn that the comment might unexpectedly extend into the next line, but this is not a concern when the next line is itself a single-line comment.

Comment: Amazingly, this issue has been going on for quite a while now in some form (at least since 2014).  I've added my issue to the end of the bug [Bug 61638 - "warning: multi-line comment" unclear and has false positives](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61638) if anyone else would like to add their 2 cents.